# I've made a subclass from the superclass but it isn't recognising the "extends"

Tags: java, netbeans

At the start of the program i've got `class BusinessAccount extends GasAccount`. `GasAccount` being the superclass and `BusinessAccount` being the subclass.

I'm also having problems with the overloading method at the bottom which is meant to be overriding the superclass method to calculate the balance of a `GasAccount`
object with the object’s discount applied to the cost of the new units which in turn will be
added to current balance of a `BusinessAccount` object. This method will return a `String` value
indicating the transaction has been successful or unsuccessful.
I have the following code for this method

```
    import java.util.Scanner ; 
class  BusinessAccount extends GasAccount
{ 
       // The objects properties are declared as private 
        private double dblDiscount ;  
        // The objects methods are defined as public 
        public BusinessAccount (int intNewAccRefNo, String strNewName, String 
                             strNewAddress,double dblNewUnits, double dblNewDiscount, int     intAccRefNo, String strName, double dblUnits, String strAddress ) 
            { 
            // The constructor - same name as the class and no return type
            dblDiscount = dblNewDiscount;
            } 

    public void setNewDiscount ( double dblNewDiscount ) 
        { 
            dblDiscount = dblNewDiscount ; 
        } // end of setNewDiscount
    public double getDiscount() 
        { 
            return dblDiscount ; 
        } // end of getDiscount method
    public string recordUnits (  double dblUnitsUsed);

     if ( dblDiscount = 0.00){
        dblBalance = (dblUnitCost * dblUnitsUsed)  + dblBalance;
            return "Successful";
            }
    else {
        dblBalance = ((dblUnitCost * dblUnitUSed) \ 100 * dblDiscount) + dblBalance;
            return "Unseccfessful";
    } // end of Override method      
} // end of class
```

Any help would be great !

Comment: Post the entire code please! Nothing can be inferred with such meager information!

Comment: `public double recordUnits` If you say it returns a `double`, return a `double`; if you want to return a `String`, say so.

Comment: Based on your description, sounds like your first problem is that your `BusinessAccount` class isn't public. The class statement should look like `public class BusinessAccount extends GasAccount`.

Comment: Semicolons after if clauses, = instead of ==...

Comment: -1 for posting unreadable, unindented code despite the fact that you've been asked to indent it, and for not posting the error messages you get.

Comment: thanks for your help, i've tried all that you've said yet it still isn't working.  it seems that the subclass isn't inheriting the properties from the superclass.

Comment: The posted code is still not indented (so you didn't try that). It still doesn't compile and still has the errors mentioned in my answer. And you still haven't posted the error messages you get from the compiler.

Comment: error messages include "public string recordUnits (  double dblUnitsUsed)" ';' expected.   "dblBalance = (dblUnitCost * dblUnitsUsed)  + dblBalance;"  cannot find symbol   "else {"  illegal start of type, initializer must be able to complete normally  " dblBalance = ((dblUnitCost * dblUnitUSed) \ 100 * dblDiscount) + dblBalance;" cannot find symbol     "return "unsuccessful" return outside method, unnecessary return statement

Answer (score 3):

public double recordUnits ( double dblUnitsUsed)

This method has been defined to return a double however your return statements are strings. If you would like to return strings the you should use:

public String recordUnits (double dblUnitsUsed){}

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is invalid: a method declaration must not have a semicolon between the closing parenthesis and the opening brace :

```
public double recordUnits(double dblUnitsUsed) // no semicolon here
{
```

Same for the if and else statements, which, if they contain more than one instruction, must enclose them inside braces:

```
if (dblDiscount = 0.00) {
    dblBalance = (dblUnitCost * dblUnitsUsed)  + dblBalance;
    return "Successful";
}
else {
    dblBalance = ((dblUnitCost * dblUnitUSed) \ 100 * dblDiscount) + dblBalance;
    return "Unsuccfessful";
}
```

Also learn to indent your code like I did above to make it readable.

And of course, as indicated in the comments, a method returning a double can't return a String.

Always read and try to understand the error messages of the compiler. If you don't understand them, post them in your question. Error messages are intended to be read, and contain meaningful information.